# Is better to make your own image or utilise the cited paper's image in a review?

Tags: publications, research-undergraduate, review-articles

**Background:** I am writing a review paper and have cited a paper who's model I want to include in the review.

**Question:** Is it better to create a picture which denotes my own understanding of the model or just copy (and cite in the caption) and add the same image as used in that paper?

I am asking because I have seen good reviews re-use the same image and just cite that paper.

Comment: Define better. Also, familiarize yourself with the concept of copyright. Good luck!

Comment: I am aware of copyright, hence the question. That's why I also explicitly said others do it. By better I mean, research in general means one's own work. Therefore, is that the "preferred" way of doing things.

Comment: Can you clarify in your question that this review paper is a class/homework assignment and not for publication.

Comment: This is for a publication!

Comment: If you publish your work, "fair use" goes out of the window. Please update your question to include the details (that you will submit this to a journal to publish). And someone can write an answer to explain the relevance of copyright to your question.

Comment: I think the "publication tag" is enough for someone to know its for a publication right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If *creat[ing] a picture which denotes [your] understanding of the model* adds value, then do that. I expect potential for added value, since that's surely an objective of your review paper. Of course, you can't add value to every image, reproducing an image (with appropriate accreditation) is fine.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Reproducing an image with appropriate accreditation is fine as far as academic integrity and plagiarism is concerned. It is *not* fine as far as copyright is concerned! You definitely need permission from the copyright holder for that...